# Visual Studio Report Designer: I don't understand group filters

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I'm writing a report that has proposal information by estimator per month. So I created a matrix where each row is grouped by estimator and each column is grouped by the month.

The thing is, my query includes data for this year AND last year, but the columns by month should only contain this year's information. So I though simple, I'll create a filter: `Year(variable_date) = Year(Today())`.

When I do this, no record information shows up. But then I changed the column to group by month AND year and suddenly, it works. Only 2015 records show up in the calculations per month.

Why did I need to group it by month AND year? Why couldn't I just group by month and have the filter remove records that didn't have the correct year using the filter group property tab?

Thanks!

P.S. I hope I have the tags right...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like month and year are separate fields. So when you group only by month it is grouping all of the rows where the value for that field is the same. (`Month=8` exists in 2014 and 2015.) The values are just numbers to SSRS and it doesn't know it needs to look at the year field too unless you tell it to.

Comment: The month and year are actually the same field, which gives the time and date. I grouped it by month by doing `=Month(variable_date)`. Sorry I realized I have a very misleading variable name in my original post and I will correct it.